# Store documents in file system instead of database in SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, persistence, document-library

In a SharePoint document library, is there any way to store the documents on the file system instead of the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make SharePoint store its documents outside the DB using the [SharePoint External Storage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897648.aspx). In other words, this isn't some functionality accessible through the SharePoint interface, but the system does offer a way of building it yourself. There are third party providers like [StoragePoint](http://www.storagepoint.com/) that will do the job for you.

Comment: If you're going to use the SharePoint External Storage API you it will be used for the whole farm. You cannot activate it for a single web application.

Comment: @Flo that is only true when using the filestream provider, not with third party tools

Answer (score 3):

Documents in a SharePoint document library will always be hosted in the database.  That said, you can access the files with a UNC path that masks the fact that they are stored in the database.

\\url\sites\yoursite\folder\

You could also write a custom solution (workflow?) that copies the files into a standard file system once they are added to a document library.