# Storing Documents and associating Metadata

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, document

This question is somewhat related to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295535/store-documents-in-file-system-instead-of-database-in-sharepoint-document-library)

I want to have document storage along with some complex metadata. I am not using sharepoint. I have a very simple directory structure that goes 2 levels deep. (One folder and documents underneath). I want to store metadata associated with each file....tags, popularity (# of times accessed), creator name, etc...

What is the best way to achieve this? I am leaning towards the relational database with the link to the file but I have to think this problem has been solved before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach sounds just fine to me. Just store the folder and filename as one of the columns values and all the other metadata in other columns.

Do you have any concerns about this approach? Or perhaps a specific part of this approach that you're not sure of how to implement?

Comment: My main concern is updating the database if a file moves. When a document is uploaded, updating the database is fine, but since the database is completely separate from the file, keeping the two in sync seems to be the tricky part.